# Serializing private members in C# recommended or not?

Tags: c#, serialization, access-modifiers

By Binary and Datacontract serializer, we can serialize the private members too.
Is it violating the oops principles? i mean by serializing we can saved the object in file , disk  and then can reuse it by anyone after deserializing. I dont know, i am thinking correct. please correct me.

Comment: Visibility isn't exactly the same thing as privacy. Any object may have any number of private fields, that's to protect the state of an object. It doesn't mean it's sensitive information.

Comment: Since you asked a philosophical question, I will add my perspective with a slightly different point of view.

I don't serialize objects with private members that have business logic around them. Because if the serialization or deserialization can change the internals and get around my business logic, then I'm not guaranteed to have an object in a valid state. Therefore I treat serialization as a boundary of my application and I only pass POCO objects through my boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intention of serialization is to put something in a format that it can be re-created with the exact same state. To be able to re-create a object with the exact same state you need to also be able to re-create the "internal sate" (aka values held by private members) too duriing the deserialization process.

So serializing private members in C# is not recommended, ***it is required***!

Comment: *To put something in a format that it can be re-created with the exact same state* is certainly the *goal* of serialization but it's not really the *meaning* of the word per se.

Comment: @AntP fair enough, but I am not sure of a better way to word it to someone who is already struggling with the concepts of serialization.

Comment: "To serialize means..." if it's a big deal.

Comment: I would have gone with "the intention of serialization is..." because to serialize really just means to put into a contiguous format, the purpose of which could vary widely.

Comment: How about : "Serialization is the process of writing the state of an object to a byte stream." - Herbert Schildt. :)